# Why do i get fsck errors?

Tags: fsck

I know how to fix fsck errors but I'm just curious why do I get them. Is it because of the hard disk pointers getting haywired ? And why doesnt such file system problems ever occur in Windows ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> why do I get them

Not because of crashes: ext3 and ext4 . If you need to do it yourself it almost always is due to hardware failure. Besides internal error messages related to fsck itself the one main other problem is hardware related. [Oracle System Administration Guide: Advanced Administration](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23823_01/html/817-0403/tsfsck-1.html) has a description on how fsck works and what different error messages it can show.,

> **General fsck Error Messages**
>
> The error messages in this section might be displayed in any phase after initialization. Although they offer the option to continue, it is generally best to regard them as fatal. They reflect a serious system failure and should be handled immediately. When confronted with such a message, terminate the program by entering n(o). If you cannot determine what caused the problem, contact your local service provider or another qualified person.
>
> **A request to move to the specified block number, disk-block-number, in the file system failed. This message indicates a serious problem, probably a hardware failure.**

A couple of things that can be a problem:

- magnetic interference (/[Degaussing](https://www.veritysystems.com/uk/news-blog/degaussing-what-you-need-to-know/))
- [moving a HDD at the moment it is written to](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hard_disk_drive#Integrity_and_failure).
- [actual physical errors on the disk introduced by the manufacturer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hard_disk_drive_failure#Example_drive_families_with_high_failure_rates).
- normal wear. An [SSD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solid-state_drive#SSD_reliability_and_failure_modes) is quick and has no moving parts like a HDD does but has a lower amount of writes to the disk.
- Or a very very bad one we had with Edge: [a bug in ext](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/317781).

---

> And why doesnt such file system problems ever occur in Windows ?

Sorry? It most certainly does. Remember those blue screen of deaths (nowaydays black screen of death). The command for a file system check is [chckdsk](https://neosmart.net/wiki/chkdsk/).

See the [Windows Hardware Error Architecture (WHEA) design guide](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/whea/).